# Can I craft a terminal to play holotapes in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

My home base is Red Rocket but I scrapped the desk with the terminal on it. Is there a terminal in the crafting menu that I can use to play holotapes?

Comment: In addition to terminals, your Pipboy can play holotapes anywhere.

Comment: I'm curious why you want one, given that you have a pip-boy on your arm.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. The terminal is under Power > Miscellaneous.

[image: build a terminal]